# JTabbedPane Transparency

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jtabbedpane, uimanager

How do you set the actual content pane's background to be Opaque, the panels that I add to it I have already set Opaque but the tabbedpane main area keeps showing up as blue even when I do

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: One what?  The question still lacks an SSCCE & you did not have time to read the linked article.

Comment: I know what SSCCE is and there is no point for it here.

Comment: Needs a picture, too. What Look & Feel? [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752037/how-to-change-background-color-of-jtabbedpane/8752166#8752166)?

Comment: *"there is no point for it here"*  There is if you want my help.  I am guessing that means you see no point to my help.  Good luck with it.

Comment: I've seen that thread trashgod, but I have tried that way and it did not work. Andrew If I post an SSCCE it will just be two lines in a main.

Comment: That duplicate would work for changing the Purple to Transparent, but that is on a JPanel and is not the actual JTabbedPane

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentOpaque", false);
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
```

Then this solves the opacity problem.

Comment: Doesn't this apply to all tabbed panes ever in the application?

Comment: It applies to all tabbed panes in the application.