# Using HTML tags in JOptionsPane

Tags: java, html, swing, joptionpane

My question today is simple. I am attempting to use HTML tags in my Java code, specifically in a JOptionsPane. I have had almost everything so far work perfectly. I know I could probably accomplish the same thing using CSS but for now I am just trying to do it with tags if possible. Here is the specific line of code giving me trouble:

```
"<br><body bgcolor=black><table border=1><font size=4 color=white>batch<font size=6 color=white>1</font> of <font size=6 color=white>"+ofFiveDisplay+"</font></table></body>"
```

What the end result should be is the text `Batch 1 of 2`. (The two is pulled from a variable) displayed on a single line in the text of the `JOptionsPane`. I want the "1" and "2" to be larger. I also want all of the text to be in white and the background of the text to be black.

I am able to add the black background and get the "1" or "2" white, but I cannot seem to change the "batch" text. Please let me know why I can not seem to change the "batch" text using the above code and what I can do to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st of all, whenever you need help post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can copy-paste it and be able to help you faster and better.

You were using `font` tag which on `HTML5` is [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp)

To get to use font sizes, etc, the best way is using CSS inside your `<html>` tags as follows:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ShowMessageDialogExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JOptionPane showMessageDialog example");
        String css = "<span style='font-size: 10; color: white; background-color: black'>";
        String batchCss = "<span style='font-size: 20;'>";
        String endSpanCss = "</span>";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "<html>" + css + batchCss + " 1 " + endSpanCss + "of" + batchCss + " 2 " + endSpanCss + endSpanCss + "</html>");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I put the CSS part inside a variable so you don't have to repeat the code each time. Hope it helps and you follow the link I left above and apply this recommendation on your next questions and answers, so they are better and more valuable.

And here's the output:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

After OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955057/using-html-tags-in-joptionspane#comment53736843_32955858)

> When I looked at the CSS guides they were a bit confusing

Here's a "[guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176981/how-to-use-html-and-css-as-a-java-application-gui)" which describes how to use `HTML5`, `CSS` and even `javascript` on a Java swing application. And another [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622446/java-swing-gui-customising-jtabbedpane-style) to the same topic.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that answered my question and gives me a place to go. When I looked at the CSS guides they were a bit confusing but the way you described it was very clear and looks easy enough to execute. Thanks for your time and well constructed answer. 

In the future I will make sure my code is executable when asking questions.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to upvote and / or accept the answer that solved your question. Good luck!

Comment: @jesric1029 see edit if you still need some help with CSS guides.

Answer (score 3):

Font is a deprecated tag and is not widely adopted so it might not work. Could you try by inlining CSS in a span like this:

```
"<span style='font-size:6; color:white'>"+ofFiveDisplay+"</span>
```