# JTabbedPane: new Tab in different color till first time opened

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I´ve got a JTabbedPane with JTextArea. An methode creates another tab an adds it to the JTabbedPane. Now I want to implement, that the new created tab gets another color untill it is opened the first time, like in a Chatroom to show that theres a new message from a specific user.
I don´t really know how do implement this. I thried to use a while-loop, but it didn´t work

```
String name = "...";
JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
textarea.setEditable(false);
textarea.setLineWrap(true);
JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textarea);
jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
tabs.add(name, jScrollPane);
tabs.setBackgroundAt(tabs.indexOfTab(name),Color.GREEN);
        while(true){
            if(tabs.getSelectedIndex() == tabs.indexOfTab(name)){
                tabs.setBackgroundAt(tabs.indexOfTab(name),Color.GRAY);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752166/230513), the following changes produce the effects illustrated below. Each tab starts as `Color.lightGray`, and a `ChangeListener` changes the background color to `Color.red.darker()` the first time each tab is selected. You can so something similar in a listener to your application's data model; several approaches are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

```
public TabColors() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        Color color = Color.lightGray;
        pane.add("Tab " + String.valueOf(i), new TabContent(i, color));
        pane.setBackgroundAt(i, color);
    }
    pane.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    pane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            pane.setBackgroundAt(pane.getSelectedIndex(), Color.red.darker());
        }
    });
    this.add(pane);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is pane? Is it a JTabbedPane? Because I cant use a ChangeListener for a JTabbedPane

Comment: _Starting from this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752166/230513)_, yes. Depending on your application's data model, you may want to use a different listener.

Comment: And which one should I use?

Comment: That depends on your application's data model. What listeners does it support?

Comment: It is an JTabbedPane with scrollable Textareas. The tabs have got JPanels with the name of the tab and a close Button

Comment: That's the view; how does your application's data model notify view(s) of new data?