# Setting background color for each tab in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, background-color, jtabbedpane

Looking at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752166/230513), I have to create a form look like: [image]

If you press the tab button, it will change the color of the background according to the color of the button.

Here is the code to do that:

```
private void jTabbedPane1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW)
};
```

and this is the result:

[image]

My problem is: I can't set the color for the whole background, and I can't change the variable name of the tab, so I can't set different events with different colors for each tab. It says that two components in the same form cannot have the same name

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's wrong? Are all your tabs making the background yellow?

Comment: there are 2 problems: i can't the set whole the background color like the first image,somehow it only change a small area.Second is i can't set different color of each tab because everytime i try to make a new event for each tab,it always send me to jTabbedPane1MouseClicked

Comment: Problem 1: It looks like you're only setting the background colour for your JTabbedPane. --- Problem 2: I need to see more code before I can understand. Maybe post your entire JTabbedPane class (and everything else that's related)?

Comment: A complete example is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752166/230513).